# Show that $f(x)=2x^2+4x+5$ is positive for all real values of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

- Show that the function $f(x)=2x^2+4x+5$ is positive for all real values of $x$.

  *At first I used completing the square technique,
  ${ax^2 + bx + c}$ is converted to
  ${a(x + h)^2 + k}$*

  $2x^2+4x+5$

  = ${2(x^2+2x+5/2)}$

  = ${2((x+1)^2+3/2)}$

  = ${2(x+1)^2+3}$

  since ${(x+1)^2}$ is always positive and the coefficient of ${x^2}$ is 2>0, 
  thus ${f(x)>0}$
- And find its minimum value.

  Again I used completing the square technique
  to find it's minimum value : 3

  ${2(x+1)^2+3}$ ≥ ${3}$
- Hence show that $0<\frac{6}{f(x)}\leq2$.

  but at last I've got trouble with this, If anyone can help, I appreciate it

Comment: $$f(x) = 2(x+1)^2+3\geq 3$$

Comment: Hi shiranz, welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site (even though Daniel answered your question already). In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Nice job editing, kudos.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks !

Comment: Um, you finishished.  (x+1)^2 ge 0 so 2 (x+1)^2 +3 ge 3.  Why did you think you had to do any more?

Comment: Finally I've got to know how to solve these

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. Try to complete the square.
2. Set the derivative equal to zero or use the formula that the minimum of $ax^2+bx+c$ is attained at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.
3. Use (2) and because $f(x)$ is positive, you may divide by $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\Delta=16-40<0$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $2>0$, thus $f(x)>0\;\forall x\in\Bbb R$.
2. $f'(x)=4x+4$ is equal to $0$ iff $x=-1$ thus $\min f=f(-1)=2-4+5=3$
3. from previous point $f(x)\ge3\;\forall x\in\Bbb R$, thus $0\le\frac1{f(x)}\le\frac13$ and multiply all three sides by $6$ your result follows.

Answer (score 0):

1) $f(x)=2x^2+4x+5=2x^2+4x+2+3=2(x^2+2x+1)+3=2(x+1)^2+3>0$

2) $f(x)=2(x+1)^2+3 \ge 3$ and if $x=-1$ that $f(-1)=3$

3) If $f(x) \ge 3$ that $$0<\frac{1}{f(x)}\le \frac 13$$
$$0<\frac{6}{f(x)}\le  2$$